# Not able to click or get element due to space before and after "shetty ruat pravin ruat(pravin.uat@gmail.com)" ..please find html code below

Tags: webdriver, xpath-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn5Y8.png) I tried,

```
xpath //h3[text()='Available Customers']/parent::div/following-sibling::div//li//div[@class='longText ng-binding ng-scope']//i[@ng-show='item.selected']
```

but it didn't work

There is space before shetty ruat pravin ruat(pravin.uat@gmail.com) so cannot reach till there and or gettext

Comment: below is html code 
    <div class="longText ng-binding ng-scope">
                <i class="fa fa-check text-success ng-hide" ng-show="item.selected"></i>
                shetty ruat pravin ruat(pravin.uat@gmail.com)
    <div style="float:right;" ng-class="{userActive: item.isActiveregistered, userInactive: item.isInactive,userActiveSent: item.isActiveSent, userActiveNotSent: item.isActiveNotSent}" class="userActiveSent"></div>

Comment: I tried xpath //h3[text()='Available Customers']/parent::div/following-sibling::div//li//div[@class='longText ng-binding ng-scope']//i[@ng-show='item.selected'] but didn't worked
    There is space before shetty ruat pravin ruat(pravin.uat@gmail.com) so cannot reach till there and or gettext

Comment: Pravin if you don't mind pls update your question with full html of this section!!

Comment: Pravin please can you clarify what element you are trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?

```
//*[contains(text(),'shetty ruat pravin')]
```

or this

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'shetty ruat pravin')]]
```

Comment: Any other solution

Comment: try this, I tested, it's workking
//*[text()[contains(.,'shetty ruat pravin')]]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li > div.longText"))));
if(element.getText().contains("shetty ruat pravin") {
element.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa")).click();
}
```